# Google Sheets find and replace regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I cannot seem to get a regexp to work in the find and replace box in my Google Sheet. I am trying to remove all of the `-` characters in any cell. Cells often look like this

```
-something
-some other stuff
-more things that-are-here
```

So I want it to end up like

```
something
some other stuff
more things that-are-here
```

I cannot even tell if this regexp thing supports RE2 properly.

[image: Example]

Supposedly this should match all `-` characters and support multi line. But it does not. It only removes the first `-` in each cell.

Comment: You may try find: "(\n|^)-" replace with: "$1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
(?<=\n|^)-
```

Here's the [test result](https://regex101.com/r/rJMO2H/1)

- `(?<=...)` Positive looksbehind
- `\n|^`

  - `\n` line break
  - `|` or
  - `^` start of the string
- `-` matches `-` literally